# Doesn't change text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that I want to take the current price in `<span id="price">`, add another price (for example, 1000) and then change `<span id="price">` to the new price. When I try, the text in `<span id="price">` just disappear. Why does it do that and how do I fix the code?

The JavaScript code:

```
function getProductPrice()
    {
        return obj.price;
    }
    function getCurrentPrice()
    {
        var price = $("#price").val();
        var price = $("#price").text();
        return price
    }
    function getTotalPrice()
    {
        var total = $(getCurrentPrice() + getProductPrice()).val();
        var total = $(getCurrentPrice() + getProductPrice()).text();
        return total;
    }
    $("#price").val(getTotalPrice());
    $("#price").text(getTotalPrice());
```

(obj.price is the price I want to add)

Comment: invalid code.. declaring `price` and `total` two times... in html page `id`s are unique... you can't properly work with multiple elements having same `id`.

Comment: I don't understand the `.text()` and `.val()` of same elem. If those are two diff elems then you have to give unique ids each elem for valid markup, if it is just single elem then there is no need to check for value `.val();`.

Comment: add your `html` markup too in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably disappearing because the value you're setting to it isn't actually there(because technically, you're adding a string to an integer if I'm guessing right). You can try something like

```
var price = parseInt($('#price').text()); //convert the text to integer
var addPrice = 1000; //the price you wanted to added
var newPrice = price + addPrice; // add them up
$('#price').text(newPrice); //voila!
```

You can change the 1000 to `obj.price` since it's the thing you wanted to added, for example.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwG44/1/) right here by the way.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to do `var addPrice = parseInt(obj.price);` for obj.price but otherwise it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the concatenation of `getCurrentPrice()` and `getProductPrice()` as jQuery selectors, but everything else about your question suggests that they are numbers.

Just use the numbers.

Don't concatenate them. Don't search the DOM for an element that matches them. Don't try to read the value or text content of that element.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't have to use jquery for total. try this:

```
 var total = parseInt(getCurrentPrice()) + parseInt(getProductPrice());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getProductPrice() {
      return obj.price;
 }
 function getCurrentPrice() {
      var price = $("#price").text();
      return price;
 }
 function getTotalPrice(){
      var total = getCurrentPrice() + getProductPrice();
      return total;
  }

  $("#price").text(getTotalPrice());
```

Comment: Ah! Typing on mobile phone is not quite fast.